# How can I change my sender name in iCloud email?

Tags: email, icloud

I want to correct how my 'sender' name appears when I write mail with my iCloud account.

For some reason, iCloud shows my first name in all caps & I can't edit it.

Comment: What do you measn by iCloud Messages? iMessages or e-mail or ... ?

Answer (score 3):

iCloud is linked directly to your Apple account. You should be able to edit the details on your Apple ID here: https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/

Comment: @Jackie - could you accept this if it solved your problem, please?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and changed my Apple ID to show regular text, not all caps, using the link provided in the first answer.  However, it didn't carry over to my outgoing email when I tried sending a test email from icloud.com a few minutes later.

I  found success using a different method:

- I logged into my account on [www.icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com), clicked on the "gear" symbol in the top right corner of the page, selected Preferences > Accounts and changed my Full Name from ALL CAPS to Regular.
- I also made the change on the Apple Mail program where I collect my iCloud email: Mail > Preferences > Accounts > Full Name (edit it to your desired style).

Answer (score 1):

You may have to change it on your iphone (if you use one) as well. Go to Settings, then Mail, contacts and Calendars, then iCloud, then Account, the Advanced (at the way bottom) - there you can change the name that goes out from the iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to change mine on my iPhone by changing the contact information in contacts - I share an iCloud email with my husband and all my messages sent from my iPhone came from him.  I deleted my email alias from his contact information and made sure my contact information had my name and my email alias - problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

There is many kind of methods to do this but none of them can do in one shot for all, means change in one place (ipad, iphone, mac pc) and them forget the other, it depends from where you would send your mails you have change in that place the id information, here is the tree methods whatever device you have.

FROM IPAD - IPHONE - IPOD TOUCH

1. OPEN SETTING (GEAR ICON)
2. GO TO MAIL, CONTACTS, CALENDARS
3. OPEN ICLOUD MAIL ACCOUNT
4. HIT ON "ACCOUNT"
5. INSIDE OF ACCOUNT WINDOW HIT ON "MAIL" OPTION
6. CHANGE THE "NAME" AS YOU DESIRE, THEN "DONE" (3 TIMES UNTIL EVERYTHING CLOSE)

FROM ICLOUD EMAIL (PC OR MAC)

1. OPEN "MAIL" ON ICLOUD (BLUE ENVELOPE ICON) (https://www.icloud.com/#mail)
2. HIT ON "GEAR ICON" (TOP RIGHT CORNER)
3. SELECT "PREFERENCE"
4. SELECT "ACCOUNT"
5. CHANGE "FULL NAME" AS YOU DESIRE, THEN DONE

FROM GMAIL ACCOUNT (YOUR ICLOUD ATTACHED TO GMAIL)

1. OPEN YOUR GMAIL ACCOUNT
2. HIT "SETTING" (GEAR ICON AT THE TOP RIGHT CORNER)
3. SELECT "SETTING"
4. CHOOSE "ACCOUNTS AND IMPORTS"
5. POINTING ON YOUR ICLOUD ACCOUNT HIT "EDIT INFO" (AT THE MIDDLE RIGHT SIDE OF YOUR SCREEN)
6. ON "EDIT EMAIL ADDRESS" SMALL WINDOW CHANGE THE "NAME" AS YOU DESIRE
7. HIT ON "NEXT STEP"
8. FINALLY HIT " SAVE CHANGES"

ALL DONE
HOPES THIS ONES HELP

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Using CAPS for the description makes it kind of hard to read (and is considered to represent shouting sometimes as well). Can you please revise your answer to make it more pleasant to the eye?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to change the prefix for @icloud.com   for example if you made  thedude@icloud.com you can't change the part "the dude" you can only make an alias.